# How to delete an animated gif from a frame with wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython, gif

I can't for the life of me figure out how to destroy or hide a gif from a wxPython frame.

Here is the example code:

```
import wx
import wx.animate


########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "GIF frame")

        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        btn1 = wx.Button(self, -1, "Start GIF",(50,10))
        btn1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton1)

        btn2 = wx.Button(self, -1, "Stop GIF",(50,40))
        btn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton2)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onButton1(self, event):
        self.animateGIF()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onButton2(self, event):
        self.animateGIF(False)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def animateGIF(self, state=True):
        gif_fname = "test.gif"
        gif = wx.animate.GIFAnimationCtrl(self, -1, gif_fname,pos=(50,70),size=(10,10))
        gif.GetPlayer()
        if state:
            gif.Play()
        else:
            gif.Stop()
            #gif.Destroy(), gif.Hide() have no effect besides cancelling the Stop() function.


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the program
app = wx.App()
frame = MyForm().Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

So, how do I go about deleting this gif from my frame ?

Thank you! I hope the code is clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are loading a new GIF every time you call animateGIF. I suggest the following, though I am sure this can be improved:

```
import wx
import wx.animate

########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "GIF frame")

        # panel not used in this example
        #panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.btn1 = wx.Button(self, -1, "Start GIF",(50,10))
        self.btn1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton1)

        self.btn2 = wx.Button(self, -1, "Stop GIF",(50,40))
        self.btn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton2)

        self.gif = None

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onButton1(self, event):
        self.animateGIF()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onButton2(self, event):
        self.animateGIF(False)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def animateGIF(self, state=True):
        if self.gif == None:
            gif_fname = "test.gif"
            self.gif = wx.animate.GIFAnimationCtrl(self, -1, gif_fname,pos=(50,70),size=(10,10))
        # call to GetPlayer was unnecessary
        #gif.GetPlayer()
        if state:
            self.gif.Play()
        else:
            self.gif.Stop()
            self.gif.Destroy()
            self.gif = None

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the program
app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = MyForm().Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: It does indeed work! Just to be sure : I was creating a second identical gif, stopping/destroying it, but the first one was still there ? Interesting, I should have seen that. Well, thanks!

Comment: @WilliamAbma Yes, you were creating a new animation on top of the old one and "stopping" it. Meanwhile the old animation continued to run underneath. If you did a `Destroy`, it would only destroy the new animation, not the old one.